# Passing a struct containing *byte to Syscall and read its content after execution

Tags: go

I'm using `syscall.Syscall(...)` to call a C method in a dll.

---

This is the C method signature:

```
SENSEI_API HSENSEI SENSEI_open(const char* sensigrafo, const char* options, SENSEI_ERR* se);
```

This is the `SENSEI_ERR` struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int code;
    char* error_string;
} SENSEI_ERR;
```

---

In my GO program I declared a struct:

```
type senseiErr struct {
    code         int
    error_string *byte
}
```

And tried to call the method:

```
    var nargs uintptr = 3
    var err senseiErr

    ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(senseiOpen),
        nargs,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr("en"))),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(""))),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&err)),
    )
```

As you may have guessed, the `SENSEI_open` method fill the `SENSEI_ERR` argument with the code and the text of the error.

Now I need to read the content of that error.

`err.code` actually has the correct value.

About `err.error_string` I don't know. I'm new to GO and i have some questions:

- Since the C struct has the field `char* error_string`, is `error_string *byte` in my GO struct correct?

  - Should I use `[]byte` or something else?
- How do I read the content of the `error_string` field?

  - `fmt.Println(err.error_string)` prints the memory address
  - `fmt.Println(*err.error_string)` prints always "101"

Comment: `101` is the the letter `e`. The [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) lists a function specifically for converting C strings to Go, called: `C.GoString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I doubt that `cost char*` meant to be UTF16 encoded. So all what you need is just getting raw data:

```golang
sensigrafo := "en\000" // \000 = 0 = null termination, \0 does not valid
options := "\000"

...

uintptr(*(*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&sensigrafo))
uintptr(*(*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&options))

// *(*unsafe.Pointer) are accessing the first field of string header:
type string struct {
    data *byte
    len int
}

// same with slices
// but for them there's less ugly way:
sensigrafo := []byte("en\000")
options := []byte("\000")

uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&sensigrafo[0]))
uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&options[0]))
```

2) C's `int` and Golang's `int` might have different sizeof, so this requires cgo declaration (`C.int`) or manual matching with random selection (try also int32, int64 if you don't want to use cgo)

```golang
type senseiErr struct {
    code         C.int /* Golang's int32/int64 */
    error_string *byte // pointer types are same as C's void* or Golang's unsafe.Pointer
}
```

Wrong offset might cause error_string be empty or point to random addr.

3) To read content you have to use same methods as C does (read data until null terminated byte, considering that *byte points to first element of string), but I propose to use already implemented runtime functions:

```golang
//go:linkname gostringn runtime.gostringn
func gostringn(p *byte, l int) string

//go:linkname findnull runtime.findnull
//go:nosplit
func findnull(s *byte) int

...

error_string := gostringn(err.error_string, findnull(err.error_string))

// or cgo one:

type senseiErr struct {
    code         C.int
    error_string *C.char
}

...

error_string := C.GoString(err.error_string)
```